# Автоматический запуск питон скриптов

Tags: python, linux, shell, cron

Дано: несколько .py файлов.
Задача: запускать их автоматически с выбранным таймаутом
Проблема: не хочу прописывать каждый в cron, а хочу прописать путь до скриптов в .sh файл и по крону запускать уже сам .sh файл.

содержимое .sh файла:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in ls /path/*.py; do python $i; done
```

путь до папки со скриптами - ну понятно, пропишу. а так все ли верно?

Comment: попробуйте в cron прописать сразу `find /path/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*.py' -exec python {} \;` без создания дополнительного скрипта sh

Comment: run-parts /path/